# How do I replace integer 1 with 'A', 2 with 'B' and so on until Z?

Tags: c#

At the moment, I am using a switch statement to check one by one for all the 26 numbers. Is there any shorter version to this?

```
public static char FormatSeatRow(int row)
    {
        switch (row)
        {
            case 1:
                return 'A';
            case 2:
                return 'B';
            case 3:
                return 'C';
            case 4:
                return 'D';
            case 5:
                return 'E';
            default:
                return '0';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using the ASCII code of the characters:

```
if(row > 0 && row <27)
    return (char)((int)'A' + row - 1);
else
    return '0';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static char FormatSeatRow(int row)
{
    if (row <= 0 || row > 26) return '0';
    int letterBase = (int)'A' - 1;
    return (char)(letterBase + row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to turn this into a one-liner.

```
public static char FormatSeatRow(int row)
    => row > 0 && row < 27 ? (char)((int)'A' + row - 1) : '0';
```